# Overwrite view path settings in lumen 5.1?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, lumen

I am developing web application using Lumen and Angularjs. My all client side files are in public folder but Lumen default view file located in `resource/view`

I want to use public folder for view files, and I updated code in `vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/view.php`
as follows,

from

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resource/view/'))
],
```

to

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('public/app/'))
],
```

It is working fine, but it is not a good solution.because when I update in next time,it will be overwritten.

So is there any method to overwrite configuration in `lumen` from outside vendor folder?

Comment: http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation#configuration-files Create your own config file and extend this option

Comment: yea.. that is the way..let me check..